# Extract minimum from array of records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A statement defines

```
<% @groups_for_unit = @groups.select{ |i| i.typeunit_id == unit.id } %>
```

to be able to present the array by typeunit_id

However this array within the greater set of data needs to have a minimum value extracted form it.

```
<%= @groups_for_unit %>
```

renders the array, but the following gives an undefined method for quantity for Array Error

```
<%= @groups_for_unit.quantity.map(&:to_i).min %>
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve the result?

Comment: You probably need `<%= @groups_for_unit.map {|g| g.quantity.to_i }.min %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) to find the group with the smallest quantity:

```
min_group = @groups_for_unit.min_by { |x| x.quantity.to_i }
```

Or `map` and `min` to find the smallest quantity:

```
min_quantity = @groups_for_unit.map { |x| x.quantity.to_i }.min
```

Comment: what do you mean *"I fail to show it in the view"*?

Comment: it is coming out as such "<Group:0x000001089ecc40>"

Comment: I guess you're calling `to_i` because of `nil` values? It might be easier to define a *default value* of 0 for `quantity`.

Comment: Actually, it was by caution/habit.  By that point there are no nil values. so, yes, `@groups_for_unit.map { |x| x.quantity }.min` runs fine.

Comment: You can shorten this to `@groups_for_unit.map(&:quantity).min`

Comment: Better yet: it returns to my origin approach highlighting the syntaxtic trip-up!